# Angular load dynamic component inside generated element

Tags: jquery, angular, components

So I am using jQuery plugin which generates some sort of elements.. My question is how can I load component inside that generated elements?

In other cases I am using `@ViewChild` to access element and create component.. but what can I do when it comes to jQuery plugin?

*Any help will be appreciated*

Comment: You are not supposed to modify the dom by hand or using jQuery, that's renderer's job, so you can't.

Comment: You are right but may be someone have found solution or tricky way to deal with that problem

Comment: I typed "solution or tricky way to deal with that problem" in Google translate and it outputs "dirty hack"... :-D

Comment: Yes it is..  :-D